# refactoring deep JSON objects in Java

Tags: java

I have currently this kind of code in my app which is very ugly but I am not sure what is the best way to refactor this to make it slightly less verbose.

So, I have something like:

```
      JsonObject a;  // initialized from some nested XML
      if (a != null) {
        JsonObject b = a.getJsonObject("b");
        if (b != null) {
          JsonObject c = b.getJsonObject("c");
          if (c != null) {
            JsonObject d = c.getJsonObject("d");
            if (d != null) {
              // update d here
              //...
              // Update c with the updated d
              c.put("d", d);

            }
          }
        }
      }
```

This is clearly ugly and I was wondering if there was a way to refactor this to make this a bit more direct and with less nesting.

Comment: Wrap in an `Optional` and `map` it?

Comment: Ohhh did not know about this. Will have a look now. Thanks @BoristheSpider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, managed it as:

```
      Optional.ofNullable(a)
        .map(e -> e.getJsonObject("b"))
        .map(e -> e.getJsonObject("c"))
        .map(e -> e.getJsonObject("d"))
        .ifPresent(e -> {
          // Do something
        });
```